# One of our Hazelcast clusters crashed and took down all other clusters as well

Tags: hazelcast

Today one of our web application servers crashed (not Hazelcast related), 
and that crash took down all other Hazelcast clusters for several minutes as well. 
We are using Hazelcast for session replication, caching and distributed statistics.

How to minimize the impact, when one cluster crashes?

Our stack:

Hazelcast 3.7.4
Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE
Spring Framework 4.3.6.RELEASE
Spring Websocket 4.3.6.RELEASE
Apache Tomcat 8.5.11
Java 1.8 112
Windows Server 2012 R2

Logs of a hazelcast cluster:

```
2017-07-07 14:41:20.177 ERROR 1600 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-20] c.p.p.r.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler : Unhandled Exception, null

com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: GetOperation invocation failed to complete due to operation-heartbeat-timeout. Current time: 2017-07-07 14:41:20.177. Total elapsed time: 121392 ms. Last operation heartbeat: never. Last operation heartbeat from member: 2017-07-07 14:39:09.296. Invocation{op=com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', identityHash=790688984, partitionId=11, replicaIndex=0, callId=0, invocationTime=1499438359178 (2017-07-07 14:39:19.178), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, name=subscription-type-by-subscription-level}, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeoutMillis=60000, firstInvocationTimeMs=1499438358785, firstInvocationTime='2017-07-07 14:39:18.785', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', target=[10.0.0.4]:5702, pendingResponse={VOID}, backupsAcksExpected=0, backupsAcksReceived=0, connection=Connection[id=6, /10.0.0.7:5702->/10.0.0.4:49193, endpoint=[10.0.0.4]:5702, alive=true, type=MEMBER]}
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.newOperationTimeoutException(InvocationFuture.java:150)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:98)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(InvocationFuture.java:74)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:376)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:307)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:94)

...

2017-07-07 14:41:40.181  WARN 1600 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-32] c.h.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl    : [10.0.0.7]:5702 [app-v19] [3.7.4] Could not get results

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: QueryOperation invocation failed to complete due to operation-heartbeat-timeout. Current time: 2017-07-07 14:41:40.181. Total elapsed time: 120624 ms. Last operation heartbeat: never. Last operation heartbeat from member: 2017-07-07 14:39:09.296. Invocation{op=com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', identityHash=2056544024, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=0, invocationTime=1499438379950 (2017-07-07 14:39:39.950), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, name=online-messaging-session-containers}, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeoutMillis=60000, firstInvocationTimeMs=1499438379557, firstInvocationTime='2017-07-07 14:39:39.557', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', target=[10.0.0.4]:5702, pendingResponse={VOID}, backupsAcksExpected=0, backupsAcksReceived=0, connection=Connection[id=6, /10.0.0.7:5702->/10.0.0.4:49193, endpoint=[10.0.0.4]:5702, alive=true, type=MEMBER]}
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.newOperationTimeoutException(InvocationFuture.java:150)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:98)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(InvocationFuture.java:74)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:158)

...


2017-07-07 14:42:58.385  WARN 1600 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-191] c.h.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl    : [10.0.0.7]:5702 [app-v19] [3.7.4] Could not get results

com.hazelcast.core.MemberLeftException: Member [10.0.0.4]:5702 - 14a2452c-45bc-40c9-bf77-ce4d73bf6f7e has left cluster!
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor$OnMemberLeftTask.run0(InvocationMonitor.java:379)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor$MonitorTask.run(InvocationMonitor.java:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Comment: Are these clusters in the same JVM?  One cluster can't bring another down, but they may have failed at the same time for the same non-Hazelcast fault giving that appearance. Coincidental timing rather than causality

Comment: What I'm getting at here is the "*noisy neighbour*" problem. If they are separate clusters they don't communicate with each other. They could have both failed at the same for the same external cause. Or the failure of one could have impacted the JVM (eg. long GC pause), causing trouble for other applications in the same JVM -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing_issues#Performance_interference_and_noisy_neighbors